# $cookieStore.get() return undefined in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, servicestack

I'm writing a cookie from a server through the response and it's fine the problem is when I try to read the same cookie using angularJs $cookieStore.get() returns always 'undefined', I have debugged with the developer tools using chrome and the cookie is there,

```
console.log($cookieStore.get("r"));
```

the $cookieStore seems to be injected and running ok, I'm just wondering why angularJs can't read the cookie.

[image: r: undefined]

[image]

**Edit:**

I tried with $cookies service and I get undefined as well.

I send the cookie in the server side without any problem, I'm getting the cookie in chrome developer tools

I'm using Service Stack and the code is the following:

```
public override object Logout(IServiceBase service, ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.Auth request)
        {
            var resp = service.RequestContext.Get<IHttpResponse>();
            resp.Cookies.AddCookie(new Cookie { Name = "r", Path = "/", Value = "from server", HttpOnly = false, Discard = false, Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(12) });
            return base.Logout(service, request);
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think [`$cookieStore`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies.$cookieStore) is only meant to be used by itself, was 'r' set somewhere else?  The docs say it provides a key/value store backed by cookies, not direct access to cookies.  When I set 'myValue' to 'jason' it stores `%22jason%22` [(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/TwsWW/).  This means you can set values to javascript objects if you want and the cookieStore will serialize and deserialize them for you.

[image]

Try using [`$cookies`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies.$cookies) instead where you can just set properties and the values aren't encoded [(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/EDtF3/1):

[image]

```
    $scope.setValue = function() {
        $cookieStore.put("myValue", $scope.value);
    };

    $scope.getValue = function() {
        $scope.value = $cookieStore.get('myValue');
    };

    $scope.setCookieValue = function() {
        $cookies.otherValue = $scope.value;
    };

    $scope.getCookieValue = function() {
        $scope.value = $cookies.otherValue;
    };
```

Comment: **was 'r' set somewhere else?**, yes it was set on the server side -I just want to have direct access to r a it´s value, I´m going to try to use $cookies instead

Comment: $cookies['r'] and $cookies.r undefined in both cases

Comment: I turned out that the cookie I was sending from the server was created with HttpOnly = true, no matter whatever the parameter I was trying to pass, fixed that with a workaround (I have to ask for this behavior) thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

Yes @Pedro is right in .NET ,for example, when doing an authentication with HttpCookie by default the attribute HttpOnly is true and in javscript -> document.cookie cant find the cookie you just saved to the browser.

It worked for me by setting to false HttpOnly when saving the cookie.

Comment: That should be a comment. with 51 reputation, you should be able to comment.